# How to cast selectedvalue of combobox to an integer?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combo box which was filled by datasource (value and id)

```
comboBox_Degree.DataSource = ds.Tables["Field"];`
comboBox_Degree.DisplayMember = "Field_Degree";
comboBox_Degree.ValueMember = "Field_ID";
```

now I want to retreive id when SelectedIndexChanged event occur. but when I cast it to an int I have such this error.

```
int fid = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox_Degree.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

error:

> *Input string was not in a correct format.*

how can I cast this value to integer?

Comment: What is the value of `comboBox_Degree.SelectedValue.ToString()` exactly?

Comment: Can you edit to include the value of the selected item?

Comment: I recommend TryParse for the conversion, this way you can evaluate against a Boolean and more gracefully handle a cast exception.

Comment: what do you mean? I think it is system.Data.DatarRowView and generally it returns some numbers.

Comment: Use `int.TryParse(comboBox_Degree.SelectedValue.ToString());` instead.

Comment: @user2944170 What are those numbers exactly?

Comment: what does TryParse exactly do?

Comment: @Soner Gönül: integer number, they are primery key of a table

Comment: TryParse does the same operation as Convert.ToInt32 except it won't throw an exception if the conversion fails. But that still won' tell us *why* the conversion is failing. Can you not break in your code and get the value `comboBox_Degree.SelectedValue.ToString()` and just post it here to remove all possible ambiguity?

Comment: Also, have you considered that the `SelectedIndexChanged` event can fire not just because of user selection, but also during data binding - and you should therefore also check that `comboBox_Degree.SelectedValue!=null` before attempting to convert...

Comment: @Stephen Byrne yeah you're right. it works. tnx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:

```
int fid;
bool parseOK = Int32.TryParse(comboBox_Degree.SelectedValue.ToString(), out fid);
```

Answer (score 5):

I usually do something like

```
int fid=0;
try {
     fid=int.Parse(comboBox_Degree.SelectedValue.ToString());
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
     //Whatever you want to do when it is not an int
    }
```

Comment: Why use a try-catch block when the TryParse method exists? See Avia's answer

Comment: Preference more than anything.  I usually want to log an error which I would put in the catch but I suppose I could take the bool and do an if (!parseOK) and then write my log.  The nice thing about the exception catch is you can catch e.Message or e.StackTrace and write to log.  Sometimes helpful, but probably less so with parsing integers.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem and I found that setting the `cbxExampleComboBox.DataSource` first then setting the `cbxExampleComboBox.ValueMember` and `cbxExampleComboBox.DisplayMember` second is the reason why when you call `cbxExampleComboBox.SelectedValue` returns an object.

Setting the `cbxExampleComboBox.ValueMember` and `cbxExampleComboBox.DisplayMember` then `cbxExampleComboBox.DataSource` will return `int` if the type of `cbxExampleComboBox.SelectedValue` is `int`.

Changing the code to the following should return the result as `int` assuming that `Field_ID` is of `int` type

```
comboBox_Degree.ValueMember = "Field_ID";
comboBox_Degree.DisplayMember = "Field_Degree";
comboBox_Degree.DataSource = ds.Tables["Field"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to solve your problem:

```
 int id = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox_Degree.SelectedValue.GetHashCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem.  However, the issue was due to the combobox setup phase firing the eventhandler.  So, I moved the `SelectedIndexChanged` EventHandler add from the `Form.Designer` to the `FormLoad` Event after the combobox setup (DataSource, ValueMember and DisplayMember assignments).

```
  // Example Combobox for Roles
  DataTable dtRoles = new DataTable();
  dtRoles = labDAO.GetRoles();
  cbxRoleID.DataSource = dtRoles;
  cbxRoleID.ValueMember = "ID";
  cbxRoleID.DisplayMember = "Name";
  cbxRoleID.SelectedIndexChanged += cbxRoleID_SelectedIndexChanged;
```